# SQL: How to avoid or deal with circular table references?

Tags: sql

I am trying to model in SQL financial assets (stocks, bonds, cash, etc), and each of those assets as a corresponding currency (USD, CAD, etc).

The way I have it modelled, currency has a "to-usd-asset' which points to a currency exchange asset (i.e. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/cadusd=x/) so I can normalize each value to one currency, but this creates a circular dependency.

Here's the quick sqlalchemy layout, although my question isn't necessarily SQLAlchemy related:

```
class Currency(Model):
    id              = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name            = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    to_usd_asset    = relationship('Asset')

class Asset(Model):
    id                      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name                    = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    symbol                  = Column(String(256))
    currency                = relationship('Currency')
```

I like this layout because it means a user holding cash, or stocks, or bonds, or whatever is just holding an 'asset', and I can see a quick and easy way to write queries that turns all values into USD (and from there to any other currency the user may care about). But the circular dependency causes a few issues including trickier insertion queries to write, sqlalchemy complains at startup about it, etc.

Is there a better table design that still accommodates what I'm after?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I do not like this model - do something similar, and I would consider this overly simplistic. THAT SAID - if it fits your needs, good. Not everyone has to deal with assets being quoted in other assets that then are quoted in one of multiple possible currencies.

Simple solution for your case: to_usd_asset is nullable. OBVIOUSLY if it is null then you have a problem there to evaluate the rate in USD, but that simple fix handles all the inserts of new currencies. And the currency having no to_usd_asset - well, that sort of is an edge case during inserts. And as NULL propagates in SQL you can throw an error if the resulting valuation should be a number but is not.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not expert of financial structures and how they work.
But intuitively i would make a kind of n-m relation between currencies and assets

Something like the following (pseudocode as i don't know SQLAlchemy)

```
Table Currency
    id     number not null PK
    name   varchar(256)


Table Asset
    id    number not null PK
    name   varchar(256)
    symbol varchar(256)

Table currency_asset
   currency_id number not null references currency,
   asset_id number not null references asset
   constraint currency_asset_pk primary key(currency_id, asset_id)
```

This gives you a lot of flexibility on association and easyness of queries. You don't mind of having some references nullable or not, and it's even not mandatory to associate a currency only to the usd change asset.

If, in plus, you need to know that a relation is the change of a currency you can add a flag to the relation itself, or a field type in the asset.

Comment: This is absolutely not what he wants - because there is only ONE reporting currency for a given asset. As such, it is not m:n. An asset is quoted (and he pretty much asks for a time series definition, not an asset definition) in a unit (which in his case is a currency). A time series is always and only quoted in ONE unit, otherwise you would not know what a price refers to. And no, if you have multiple price quotes it is not m:n either as you may have the same currency multiple times in different markets. The OP model is overly simplistic (and may fit his needs) - your model sadly is not  fit.